# Nest Device Access Rate Limits for Commercial Production

Tags: nest-device-access

In [Device Access Sandbox](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/project/limits) the rate limits are clearly identified in the documentation, but I couldn't find what are the rate limits in [Commercial Production](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/project/apply#certification_for_commercial_production). Anyone can share any information on that?

Answer (score 0):

Google will set the limit based on your userbase.